# Installing exe through batch file

Tags: file, batch-file

I am trying to install through batch file..

```
ECHO OFF

ECHO Installing MySoftware . . .
"%~dp0\MySoftware.exe" /S /v/qn"UPGRADEADD=link goes here"

pause
```

but it fails to install.

Comment: without the context it is hard to answer anything. You haven't mentioned what you are installing, nor what error you're getting.

Comment: I am not getting error : the console just just says press any key to continue..I just want to know whether there is any syntax error.

Comment: You mean it doesn't even display `Installing MySoftware . . .`? That would be weird. Anyway, have you tried running the `.exe` at the command prompt using the same command line (only specifying the full path explicitly instead of `%~dp0`, of course)? This may turn out an issue that has nothing to do with batch files.

Comment: No..after saying..Installing Mysoftware...it says press any key to continue after 40-50 secs.

Comment: See addition to my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Not much info to go on.  What you have will not work if executed from a UNC drive and may not work if you 'Run as administrator' because the current directory gets changed.  Try this.  Of course that may not fix it and further details would be nice.

```
@ECHO OFF
PUSHD "%~dp0"

ECHO Installing MySoftware . . .
"MySoftware.exe" /S /v/qn"UPGRADEADD=link goes here"
```

Adding to my answer based on comments provided.
Presumably your bat file is in the same folder as MySoftware.exe.  If it takes that long, it sounds like the install is working.  Try doing

```
"MySoftware.exe" /?
```

That may give you a help screen to tell you more about the arguments beng passed.  Also, try what you are now doing without the /S (which probably specifies a "silent" install... which is why you don't see anything.

Comment: I am trying this on win7 and i have no idea ,which is the current directory by default.Also if there is any reference which can help me about some basics will help.

Answer (score 0):

**PART 1** - If you want to create a "Setup" File in batch.

Maybe it works, but this is will be very hard to you for done this program.

Let's call the EXE File "Game1:

I will recommend you to take all the Game1 file's code (Maybe you can use the program Notepad++ for do this) after you taked Game1's code do this like i writing here

Let's say that the code of Game1 is:

```
ABC
```

Copy the code, then go to the batch file.

The "Setup" file of Game1 HAVE to come with a empty EXE file.

You can make a empty EXE file with notepad - just save the file as:

Name.exe

Then you doing at the batch file script this thing:

```
set %something%=ABC
```

After you done this you adding this to the batch script:

```
Echo %something% >> Name.exe
```

Don't forget to name the EXE file at the name of the program / game.

And now, if this message didn't help to you, maybe you need to make a EXE from batch file.

**PART 2** - If you want to make an EXE file of batch file.

Open the start menu of Windows and search this:
**IExpress**
Don't let the computer search for you the full name, its working only if you wtiting the full name.

After you search IExpress, click on "Activate Command".

Click on Next, Don't change the first options.
Click on "Extract files only" and click on Next.
Name the EXE program and click Next.
Stay on "No prompt." and continue.
Now you can display a program License. if you want do a txt file and choose the display option.
Add batch files and click Next.
click on the option you want and click Next.
If you want a finish message, click on display message and write the message.
Here browse where the EXE will be and choose your options, click Next.
click Next.

Wow that's was super-long! Hope I helped you!